# how to encode an array of bytes to recordIO protobuf format in python and sagMaker

Tags: image, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, amazon-sagemaker

I tried to invoke sageMaker endpoint with `content-type:application/json`, where my request has this format:

```
{'latents': [latents], 'keypoints': [keypoint], 'article_streams': [list_of_images]}]
```

but the call failed as it is not possible to encode an array of bytes (images) using json.

`Bytes are not json serializable`

I tried then to use `content-type:x-recordio-protobuf` but I could not find how to convert an array of bytes to recordIO protobuf format, does anyone have an idea how can this be done?
thanks

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: If you found a solution please post it